# Ensure knockout binding gets processed first

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a table created from an observable array. Table rows contains elements belonging each to one of a set of categories. To filter the table based on categories, there is a row of buttons.

Buttons can be active or inactive, indicated via a CSS class bound via knockout:

```
<button data-bind="click: filter.filterCategory, css: { filterOn: filter.category.isFiltered() }">Filter</button>
```

Filtering within the table is done by switching the display state of rows:

```
<tr data-bind="css: { nonDisplay: !table.category.isDisplayed() }">
</tr>
```

The click handler mainly sets the values of the two observables, in sequence e.g.

```
vm.filter.category.isFiltered(true);

vm.table.category.isDisplayed(false);
```

This works in principle.

The problem is that the indication that the filter button has been selected by the user is not given immediately, but dependent on the execution time of the filtering itself, i.e. the changes to the table.

With larger tables, and especially on mobile, this can mean delays of a couple of seconds.

I can live with the filtering itself taking this long, but the feedback needs to be immediate.

Is there a way to ensure that the change on `vm.filter.category.isFiltered` gets applied before the longer running change based on `vm.table.category.isDisplayed` is started?

Answer (score 0):

This seems as an async fail.
You should implement a callback method parameter in the isFiltered method, something like this

```
var vm = vm || {};
vm.filter = vm.filter || {};

vm.filter.category = (function($){
    var that = this;

    that.isFiltered = function(booleanValue, callback) {

            // Put your primary code here
        console.log("this runs first");

            // ...when the first code is done 
        callback();

    };

    that.isDisplayed = function(booleanValue) {
        console.log("this runs second");
    };

    return that;
})($);

// Implement by stating a method as the second parameter.
vm.filter.category.isFiltered(true, function(){ vm.filter.category.isDisplayed(false); });
```

This will render

```
// this runs first
// this runs second
```

Comment: I don't get it - what is the difference between setting the two observables sequentially and this? (Went with a timeout solution before reading this, and don't want to restructure my code again to give this a try.)

Comment: @gzost Well a timeout will only work if your content is reloaded/reconstructed within that actual time you set. The pattern above supports asynchronous loading and you should probably read some more on that if you are using knockout! :)